# Passing callback function to React component as prop – less verbose way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I am new to React, so please bear with me – I would be delighted if this were already answered somewhere.

To get my feet wet, I  started building a simple button component:

```
const Button = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return(
            <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick}>Hallo Button</button>
        )
    },

    onClick() {
        this.props.onButtonClick()
    },
})
```

This button component is owned by another component I call `App`:

```
const App = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hallo Welt</h1>
                <Button onButtonClick={this.handleButtonClick}/>
            </div>
        )
    },

    handleButtonClick() {
        console.log('Button clicked')
    },
})
```

See how I passed `App`'s `handleButtonClick()` method as a prop to the button component. I got this idea from the [official React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#callbacks-as-props).

It works and since I got this from an official source, I assume this is good practice – but to me this seems a bit cumbersome. Are there any other ways to pass on callback functions in React – maybe shorter or less verbose?

Comment: This is the best practice

Answer (score 0):

React has [`Context`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) to simplify this, although the authors consider explicitly passing handlers to be a superior approach.